# Reverse geocoding from sql server

Tags: sql-server, reverse-geocoding

I have a lot long/lat data in MS SQL Server, i want to do reverse geocoding by using openstreetmaps or some other free web service, and on the end i want to display all of that in report builder, does anyone tried something similar? How to pass my coordinates to web server, and how to receive answer and put it in some fields?

Comment: you will need some javascript, php or python to retrieve the lat/lng from the database and then use an api to request the address like http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?latlng=23.0043673,72.5411868999996&sensor=false for xml response